# How to correct content-disposition error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Thanks always for your support. I am currently trying to upload media through ajax/jquery. I could upload image, but anytime i tried to upload video, i was formerly getting no content-disposition supplied. so i added this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=small.mp4");
```

and what i get now is header preflight issue:

Failed to load http://myurl/wp-json/wp/v2/media: Request header field content-Disposition is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

this is my wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js|mp4)$">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Accept"

</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

my request code is as thus:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://myurl/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        contentType: false,

        contentDisposition: 'form-data',//'attachment, filename="small.mp4"',
        //contentDisposition: 'attachment, filename="small.mp4"'
        processData: false,

        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode( 'admin:Rastrastvibe' ) );
            xhr.setRequestHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=small.mp4");

        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
            var featuredimageid = data.id;
            formData.append("featured_media", featuredimageid);


            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://myurl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode( 'admin:pass' ) );
                },
                success: function( data ) {

                    console.log( data );
           // var featuredimage= data.id;
           // console.log(featuredimage);



       },
       error: function( error ) {
        console.log( error );

    }
});


        },
        error: function( error ) {
            console.log( error );


        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks community, I got it sorted. first i re-edit my wordpress .htaccess as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Accept"
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

Then I used my form to submit the file instead of providing file location thru a formdata object cos I had boycotted file input of my form sending the file. Now to my next challenge of add both featured image and video attachment.